# spark netty version issue

Tags: apache-spark, netty, amazon-emr

I am using redis client in spark job and getting an exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.config()Lio/netty/bootstrap/BootstrapConfig;
    at org.redisson.client.RedisClient$1$1.operationComplete(RedisClient.java:234)

Its due to netty version mismatch

Spark used netty version netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.23 but redis needs 4.1 , Is it possible to override netty jar in spark-submit command for both driver and executor .

Comment: did you try https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are assembling your project.

Basically we create a fat jar containing all dependencies inside with `maven-shade-plugin` or `maven-assembly-plugin`. So to avoid this issue you can specify relocation in the shade plugin configuration. It looks something like this:

```
<relocations>
     <relocation>
          <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
          <shadedPattern>your.prefix.io.netty</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
 </relocations>
```